# Crossbow Expert + Mobile Feat

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, ranged-attack

I’m having some troubles interpreting the wording of these two and the ways in which I can combine them. The basic idea would be:

1. Load and equip a hand crossbow before combat, along with a rapier in the other hand.
2. Attack with the rapier, follow up with crossbow as bonus action, without disadvantage in melee range, both due to *crossbow expert feat* and then move away from the enemy, avoiding opportunity attacks due to the *mobile feat*.
3. Sheathe rapier, throw a throwing knife, dart etc., and follow up with crossbow as bonus action, as the *crossbow expert feat* lets me ignore the loading quality of the crossbow as long as I have a hand free, which I would after throwing the dart/knife.
4. Fire crossbow as bonus action, still ignoring the loading as I still have a free hand, and then drawing my rapier and attacking, as drawing attacking counts as same action, and then move away, ignoring opportunity attack from *mobile feat*.

I have looked all parts of this over, and can't see any reason for this not to work, but am I missing something? As far as I can tell Dual Wielding shouldn’t be necessary, because crossbow experts states that:

> When you use the attack action and use a one handed weapon, you can
>   use a bonus action to attack with a loaded hand crossbow you carry.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/95413/28464

Comment: The feat no longer specifies **loaded** hand crossbow. So you don't need to throw things in step 3. Just sheath your rapier and use your action to shoot the enemy with the one-handed weapon (hand crossbow) you're still holding while ignoring the loading property, then continue to ignore the loading property and use your bonus action to shoot the hand crossbow.
But step 4 needs to be done in reverse order, bonus actions come after the action that enables them. If an enemy's reaction stopped you from making your Attack action after using the crossbow, you've wouldn't have been able to do it.

Answer (score 20):

### You're missing one thing:

You've used two actions in number 3.

You sheathe your rapier and draw a dagger/knife/dart from some sort of storage. Sheathing the rapier can be done for "free" (first bullet of "Interacting With Objects Around You," PHB p.190). But then drawing the dagger/dart would require the Use an Object action, per "Other Activity on Your Turn," same page. Attacking with the thrown weapon also requires an action, but you're out.

---

Your proposed scheme had you making six attacks in three rounds. I think you can use the same thinking and still respect the action economy by making one slight alteration. You run into the same draw/sheathe economy problem in a hypothetical fourth round, but the fight's likely over by then. So here's your original scheme, with a small modification:

1. Load and equip a hand crossbow before combat, along with a rapier in the other hand.
2. Attack with the rapier, follow up with crossbow as bonus action, without disadvantage in melee range, both due to *crossbow expert feat* and then move away from the enemy, avoiding opportunity attacks due to the *mobile feat*. ***Now sheathe the rapier, for "free".***
3. ***Draw knife/dart for "free"***, throw a throwing knife, dart etc., and follow up with crossbow as bonus action, as the *crossbow expert feat* lets me ignore the loading quality of the crossbow as long as I have a hand free, which I would after throwing the dart/knife.
4. Fire crossbow as bonus action, still ignoring the loading as I still have a free hand, and then drawing my rapier and attacking, as drawing attacking counts as same action, and then move away, ignoring opportunity attack from *mobile feat*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62856/discussion-on-answer-by-nitsua60-crossbow-expert-mobile-feat).